# TensorFlow, use map_fn to iterate each row and do calculation task

Tags: tensorflow

I defined a function `fn` to calculate the result of each row and I defined the code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 1]])
b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]])
c = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1]])

def fn(v1, v2, v3):  # v1, v2, v3 are rows of np.array
    return v1[0]*v1[1] + v2[0]*v2[1] + v3[0]*v3[1]

tf.map_fn(lambda v1, v2, v3: fn(v1, v2, v3), (a, b, c))
```

However, the above code can not work, how can I fix it?

I define a function `f3`

```
def f3(a):
    return a[0] + a[1]

tf.map_fn(f3, a)  # there is no error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tf.stack()` can solve my problem

```
tf.map_fn(lambda v1, v2, v3: fn(v1, v2, v3), tf.stack([a, b, c], 1))
```